# Как объединить два where

Tags: sql

Первый запрос пример:

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE 
    s.OrderID in (SELECT * FROM SacuraOnline.[dbo].[splitstring](@orders))
```

Второй запрос пример:

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE 
    convert(date,DATE_OPER) BETWEEN @date_from and @date_to order by date_oper desc`
```

Задача: нужно объединить два where в один запрос, но условие такое если @orders = 0, то выполняется второе where если нет то первое

Пыталcя так:

```
select * 
from table 
where 
    iif(@orders==0,
        s.OrderID in (SELECT * 
                      FROM SacuraOnline.[dbo].[splitstring](@orders)),
        convert(date,DATE_OPER) 
        BETWEEN @date_from and @date_to order by date_oper desc)
```

Как лучше сделать, подскажите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
   *
From table
Where (@orders=0 and
       s.OrderID in
           (SELECT * FROM SacuraOnline.[dbo].[splitstring](@orders))
   or (@orders=1 and
       convert(date,DATE_OPER) BETWEEN @date_from and @date_to)
order by date_oper desc
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. :)